# Search region instead of search inside region

Tags: search

When a region is active, emacs searches (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) within that region.

I would like to change that so that it searches in the whole buffer with the region as pattern.

Any toughs ?

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate. I'll vote to close this question.

Comment: FWIW, it is *not* the case that when the region is active vanilla Isearch searches only within the region. For that you need [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus).